# How to install adobe flash player plugin in RHEL 6?

Tags: plugins, rhel-6

How to install adobe flash player plugin in RHEL 6? I am using Google chrome.

I have installed  `adobe-release-i386-1.0-1.noarch` and `flash-plugin-10.3.181.26-release.i386`
 Now what to do?

PS: I don't have RHN support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [this procedure](http://chankeypathak.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-insall-adobe-flash-player-in.html) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Adobe's home page](http://www.adobe.com/), click on "Adobe Flash Player" under "Downloads", and follow the instructions.

Comment: I have installed adobe-release-i386-1.0-1.noarch

Comment: flash-plugin-10.3.181.26-release.i386 is installed.

Comment: Okay, so what's the problem then?

Comment: Still not able to see flash videos on youtube.

Comment: Did you restart your browser? Are you running a ix86 version of the browser?

Comment: Yes I restarted my browser. No I am using x86_64 version.

Comment: Well there's your problem. The browser can't find the plugin. Either install the ix86 version of the browser (recommended), use nspluginwrapper, or use the pre-release x86_64 Flash plugin (not recommended).

Comment: ix86 version of ADOBE FLASH PLAYER ?

Comment: Package nspluginwrapper-1.3.0-14.el6.x86_64 already installed

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/648/discussion-between-chankey-pathak-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams)